# Reducing if/else statement complexity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a concise if/else statement below:

```
function () {
    if (elem.attr('data-src-1') === '' && elem.attr('data-src-2') === '') {
      // scenario a
    } else if (elem.attr('data-src-1') === '' && elem.attr('data-src-2') !== '') {
      // scenario b
    } else if (elem.attr('data-src-1') !== '' && elem.attr('data-src-2') === '') {
      // scenario c
    } else {
      // scenario d
    }
}
```

which is returning a complexity of 7 by strict linting rules. I need to reduce its complexity to 6 but can't see how to make it more concise?

Comment: What are these scenarios doing?

Comment: You could just check data-src-1 (only) once in an if block, then in an inner if block, have scenarios a and b with the two states of data-src-2. Then in an else block, check data-src-2 and do scenarios c and d.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity is a poor measure of code quality. I really have no idea why anyone uses it.

Comment: @Liam I agree...and complexity is limited to 7 max.

Comment: So you'll end up re-writing this to be less readable to get it under 7...Craziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a code review question, but you could combine the `if 1=''` into if/elses, then do the same for the interiors if/elses.

I think this is less readable, but it **is** technically less complex.

```js
function() {
  if (elem.attr('data-src-1') === '') {
    if (elem.attr('data-src-2') === '') {
      // scenario a
    } 
    else {
      // scenario b
    }
  } else if (elem.attr('data-src-2') === '') {
    // scenario c
  } 
  else {
    // scenario d
  }
}
```

Comment: I re-structured my code to look more like this and it reduced its complexity to 6 - thanks! I will mark this as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

More readable one (at least for me)

```
let data1 = elem.attr('data-src-1') === ''
let data2 = elem.attr('data-src-2') === ''

if (data1)
    !data2 ? console.log(" scenario a ")  : console.log(" scenario b ") 
else
    data2 ?  console.log(" scenario c ") : console.log(" scenario d ")
```

Comment: You could take it one step further and put it all into one giant ternary operation. `data1 ? (!data2 ? console.log(" scenario a ")  : console.log(" scenario b ") ) : (data2 ?  console.log(" scenario c ") : console.log(" scenario d "))`, but this looks horrible haha

Comment: But your logic is wrong, `data2` is a/b and `!data2` is c/d, not the way you have it.